# How to display data from selecting option in drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

From my device table, I have device id, device name and image id and my drop down currently displays the the respective devices. How can I display the image id that is respective to the device selected on. I've tried messing around the code but I'm still going no where.

```
<select class = "form-control" id="changeDevice" name="changeDevice" >
   <option value= "  -- select a device -- " disabled selected value> -- select a device -- </option> 
        <?php
          foreach($device as $devicedrop){
          ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $devicedrop['id'] ?>">
    <?php echo $devicedrop['name'] ?> </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
</select>  
    <input type = "text" id="text"></input>
<script>
    $('#changeDevice').find('option:selected').text();
    var text = $(this);
    $('#text').prop(text);
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#text').prop(text);` what is this used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take 'selectedIndex' property of select element. and...

```
<script>
    var device = $('#changeDevice');
    var selectedIndex = device.prop('selectedIndex');
    var text = $('option', device).eq(selectedIndex).text().trim();
    $('#text').val(text);
</script>
```

---- Edit

Well. It's you again Lotse. :)

You can store your data into DOM element (option) like...

```
<?php
  $rows = ...;
  foreach($rows as $row) {
    printf('<option value="%d" data-image-id="%d" data-image-name="%s" data-device-name="%s">%s</option>', $row['id'], $row['image_id'], $row['device_name'], ...);
  }
?>
```

this code generate HTML as

```
<select id="#device_option">
  <option value="1" data-image-id="32" data-image-name="sample-01.jpg" data-device-name="some name">...</option>
  ...
</select>
```

then, now you can pick up any data from jQuery's $.data(key) function.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('device_option').on('change', function() {
      var options = $('option:selected', this); // take care when multiselect on
      var val = $(this).val(); // or options.val()
      var image_id = options.data('image-id');
      var image_name = options.data('image-name');
      var device_id = options.data('device-name');
      var text = options.text().trim();

      // you can poll data from DOM

    });
  });
</script>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Thanks Yourim, I just needed to add onchange for it to work the way I wanted. One more thing, how can i get it too echo the image id rather than the device name? The image id is also part of one record.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try work on it and see what I'll get